jax complaining about static start/stop/step
Here is a very simple computation in jax which errors out with complaints about static indices:
def get_slice(ar, k, I):
  return ar[i:i+k]

vec_get_slice = jax.vmap(get_slice, in_axes=(None, None, 0))

arr = jnp.array([1, 2,3, 4, 5])

vec_get_slice(arr, 2, jnp.arange(3))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-6c60650ce6b7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 vec_get_slice(arr, 2, jnp.arange(3))

    [... skipping hidden 3 frame]

4 frames
<ipython-input-29-9528369725c2> in get_slice(ar, k, i)
      1 def get_slice(ar, k, i):
----> 2   return ar[i:i+k]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/array.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    346           return out
    347 
--> 348     return lax_numpy._rewriting_take(self, idx)
    349 
    350   def __iter__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py in _rewriting_take(arr, idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   4602 
   4603   treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx = _split_index_for_jit(idx, arr.shape)
-> 4604   return _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
   4605                  unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   4606 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py in _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   4611             unique_indices, mode, fill_value):
   4612   idx = _merge_static_and_dynamic_indices(treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx)
-> 4613   indexer = _index_to_gather(shape(arr), idx)  # shared with _scatter_update
   4614   y = arr
   4615 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py in _index_to_gather(x_shape, idx, normalize_indices)
   4854                "dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized "
   4855                "arrays within JIT compiled functions).")
-> 4856         raise IndexError(msg)
   4857 
   4858       start, step, slice_size = _preprocess_slice(i, x_shape[x_axis])

Horrible error output below. I am obviously missing something simple, but what?


IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax. Found slice(Traced<ShapedArray(int32[])>with<BatchTrace(level=1/0)> with
  val = Array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
  batch_dim = 0, Traced<ShapedArray(int32[])>with<BatchTrace(level=1/0)> with
  val = Array([2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
  batch_dim = 0, None). To index a statically sized array at a dynamic position, try lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized arrays within JIT compiled functions).


Indices passed to slices in JAX must be static. Values that are mapped over in vmap are not static: because you're mapping over the start indices, your indices are not static and you see this error.
There is good news though: the size of your subarray is controlled by k, which is unmapped in your code and therefore static; it's only the location of the slice (given by I) that is dynamic. This is exactly the situation that jax.lax.dynamic_slicewas designed for, and so you can rewrite your code like this:
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def get_slice(ar, k, I):
  return jax.lax.dynamic_slice(ar, (I,), (k,))

vec_get_slice = jax.vmap(get_slice, in_axes=(None, None, 0))

arr = jnp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

vec_get_slice(arr, 2, jnp.arange(3))
# Array([[1, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [3, 4]], dtype=int32)


Thank you! I have been trying to grok Jax's idiosyncrasies, with intermittent success...

This particular issue stems from the static shape requirement (see JAX sharp bits: dynamic shapes). If slice indices are dynamic, the output of the slice operation would be dynamically-shaped, which is not allowed.
